# "Do pole vault" or "perform pole vault"?

Tags: word-choice, collocations

Could tell me which verb do you use with the sport of pole vault: *do* or *perform*? For example:

> Person A: Do you do any sports?
>
> Person B: Yes, I **do**/**perform** pole vault.

Interestingly, there is no results on [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20pole%20vault%2Cperform%20pole%20vault&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) for either. What do you say then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use "pole-vault" as a verb

> Yes, I pole-vault.

or perhaps more naturally

> Yes, I'm a pole-vaulter.

Actually, while pole-vaulting might be a person's specialism, it is unlikely to be the only form of athletics a person does. So a fluent response might be.

> Yes.  I'm a member of my local athletics club, where I specialise in the pole vault, but I also sprint and do long jump, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you clearify a few things? You wrote "do long jump" but not "do pole vault". Why I can't say "do pole vault"? You also use "the" before "before pole vault" is it optional?

Comment: Well spotted!  You can say both, I used "do long jump" to add variety (and see if you are reading carefully).  "The pole vault" is the name of an event in a competition (ie the Olympic rules of the pole vault, not just jumping with a stick). This sentence works better with "the".

Comment: One more question please! "I do pole vault" or "I do pole vaulting"?